# Milliseconds between two dates in c# | one date is fixed and another date should be given as console input

Tags: c#

Write a C# program to get a Date as String in the format “dd/MM/yyyy” and to print the Date in the specified format shown in sample output and to illustrate the use of TotalMilliseconds method in the DateTime Class.

Hint :

Use appropriate methods / constructors defined in the DateTime class.

TheTotalMilliseconds method returns how many milliseconds have passed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Input and Output Format:

Refer sample input and output for formatting specifications.

All text in bold corresponds to input and the rest corresponds to output.

Sample Input and Output:

Enter the input value

27/01/1978

The input date is 1/27/1978 12:00:00 AM

Milli-Seconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 is 254687400000

i have written the code but it shows the answer as "254707200000"

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
public class sample {

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string s1;
        DateTime dat = new DateTime(1970,01,01);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the input value");
        s1=Console.ReadLine();
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("te-IN");
        DateTime temp = Convert.ToDateTime(s1, culture);
        Console.WriteLine("The input date is "+temp.ToString());
        double x = (dat-temp).TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Milli-Seconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 is "+x);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You could improve this question by specifying what exactly is not working. E.g., include your code.

Comment: Are you outputting the variable containing the milliseconds only?
Hard to answer without any code to inspect. But if you save the input variable(var1) and variable for the milliseconds(var2) make sure to output both var1 & var2( E.g Console.WriteLine("Milli-Seconds that have passed since" + var1 + " is " + var2)

Comment: Please check my answer.   I posted a link with a Unix Epoch converter which is exactly what you are trying to achieve.  In there you can plug your dates and see the result to compare with your results.

Comment: You should do `(temp-dat)` or else you'll get a negative number (since `dat` is the earlier (smaller) of the two dates)

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(dat.AddMilliseconds(254687400000).ToString());` produces the string: `"01/26/78 06:30:00 PM"`, so I don't know where you got the idea that *"Milli-Seconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 is 254687400000"*

Comment: Please don't just post your assignment. There's no question here; what specific question do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are getting is correct: 254707200000.  That is how many milliseconds have passed since 12 AM on 1/1/1970 until Januray 27th 1978 at 00:00:00 which is the same as 12AM.

Very easy to corroborate here in the Unix Epoch converter:

[Unix Timestamp Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Furthermore the number you want "254687400000" is actually Thursday, January 26, 1978 6:30:00 PM GMT.....

So I am not sure where you got that number.  But C# is giving you the right answer.

Comment: Hi, yes, you are correct. The above code of mine gives the correct answer. Thanks for the help BTW.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
public class sample {

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string s1;
        DateTime dat = new DateTime(1970,01,01);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the input value");
        s1=Console.ReadLine();
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("te-IN");
        DateTime temp = Convert.ToDateTime(s1, culture);
        Console.WriteLine("The input date is "+temp.ToString());
        double x = (dat-temp).TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Milli-Seconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 is "+x);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The above code is working fine.. Thanks for your help!! Happy coding.